# Identify the custom user model in REST_FRAMEWORK settings Django

Tags: django-models, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-custom-user

I'm new in Django `rest_framework`. I'm using a custom user model and `djoser` as my authentication system. I want to use my custom user model in the `djoser` register view and I don't know how to identify that in the `rest_framework` settings?

settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSIONS_CLASSES':(
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
}
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager


class MyAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, username, phone, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Users must have an email address")
        if not username:
            raise ValueError("Users must have an username")
        if not phone:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a phone number")

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username=username,
            phone=phone
            )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
    
    def create_superuser(self,email, username, phone, password):
        user = self.create_user(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username=username,
            phone=phone,
            password=password
            )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True

        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email",max_length=60, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=60,unique=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=60,unique=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="date joined",auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="last login",auto_now=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=60,null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=60,null=True)
    wilaya = models.CharField(max_length=60,null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=60,null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    store_coordinates = models.CharField(max_length=60,null=True)
    documents1 = models.CharField(max_length=60,null=True)
    documents2 = models.CharField(max_length=60,null=True)


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email','phone']
    

    objects = MyAccountManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
        
    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin
    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
```

What should I add to use my custom user model in `djoser` register view?

Answer (score 0):

You're doing almost everything right, but you need to tell Django in the settings what user model it should use.

In `models.py` use something like this

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from .managers import UserManager

class User(AbstractUser):
    # Add whatever fields you want

    # Use your custom manager
    objects = UserManager()
```

In `settings.py`

```py
# Tell Django what user model should be used
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'auth.User'  # app_label.model
```

make sure you use `python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate` to create your custom user model.

Enjoy!